# xslcompiledtransform outputs name of function and namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

Background:
I am developing an XSLT to transform an XML document into an rtf document.  The XSLT has an msxsl:script function called GetImageString that returns a string representation of the given image file so I can embed the image in the rtf document.

The problem:
When xslCompiledTransform is used with xmlWriterSettings and XmlWriter the output of the transformation (xsl:output method="text") includes the name of the script function (GetImageString) along with a listing of all the non-default namespaces included in the XSL file.  If I use XslCompiledTransform without the xmlWriterSettings and XmlWriter classes, the output is correct, except that in inserts the BOM (byte order marks) at the top of the file which confuses (at least) the MS Word rtf reader.  So to supress the BOM, I have to use the XmlWritterSettings (and the XmlWriter) class, but then the output isn't correct when the embedded c# code is called.

Here is a snippet of my xsl file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xpp="http://www.sdl.com/xpp"
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:rend="urn:rend-scripts">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="xpp:document">          
      <xsl:text>{\rtf1\ansi {\fonttbl </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//xpp:style"/>
      <xsl:text> }</xsl:text>

      <xsl:apply-templates select ="//xpp:image"/>
      <xsl:text>};</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <msxsl:script language="c#" implements-prefix="rend">
      <msxsl:assembly href="C:\Projects\LearningRTF\System.IO.dll"/>
      <msxsl:assembly href="C:\Projects\LearningRTF\System.Drawing.dll"/>
      <msxsl:using namespace="System.IO"/>
      <msxsl:using namespace="System.Drawing"/>
      <![CDATA[
        public string GetImageString(string path_to_image){
          MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
          Image img = Image.FromFile(path_to_image);
          img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
          byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
          string output = BitConverter.ToString(bytes, 0).Replace("-", string.Empty);

          return output;
        }
      ]]>
    </msxsl:script>

    <xsl:template match="xpp:image">
      <xsl:text>
      {\pict\wmetafile8</xsl:text>
      <GetImageString>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="rend:GetImageString(@path)"/>
      </GetImageString>
      <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
```

Here is the c# program calling the transformation:

```
    public void TransformWithMS()
    {
        XsltSettings xsltConfig = new XsltSettings(false,true);

        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load("scratch.xsl",xsltConfig,null);
        //xslt.Transform("divxml_modified.xml", "scratch.rtf");
        XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xmlWriterSettings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
        xmlWriterSettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
        XmlWriter results = XmlWriter.Create("scratch.rtf", xmlWriterSettings);
        xslt.Transform("divxml_modified.xml", results);
    }
```

This is what the offending output looks like:

> {\rtf1\ansi {\fonttbl
>        {\f1 Times New Roman;} }
>   {\pict\wmetafile8 **GetImageString xmlns:xpp="http://www.sdl.com/xpp" >xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" >xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" >xmlns:rend="urn:rend-scripts"** 49492A00BC480000803...

(There is a < and a > around the GetImageString and list of namespcaes but I'm having trouble figuring out how to format that into the question)

Anyone know how to call an msxsl:script function without the function name and extra namespaces being output (and without the BOM)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change a setting of the output from .NET code then you should use

```
XmlWriterSettings myOutputSettings = xslt.OutputSettings.Clone();
myOutputSettings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
```

Now create an XmlWriter e.g.

```
using (XmlWriter result = XmlWriter.Create("scratch.rtf", myOutputSettings))
{
  xslt.Transform("divxml_modified.xml", result);
}
```

That allows you to have an XmlWriter which outputs according to the `xsl:output` but with the encoding changed.

Whether that fixes the problem with the code being appearing in the output I am not sure, try and report back.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Using `Clone` to create the XmlWriterSettings did the trick.  Someone on another forum suggested that the <GetImageString></GetImageString> tags were unnecessary and by removing those, I was able to make it work as expected as well.